# Movesense low level API

Tags: movesense

I am planning to connect Movesense to Arduino with BLE Shield.
Where I can get deep protocol description to get position data from the Movesense? Do this information public?
On Android I have library mdslib-1.39.0(1)-release.aar that allows connection to Movesense, but have not able to get code from it, to create Arduino connection to Movesense, based on Android sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Whiteboard protocol" that MDS implements on top of BLE is quite complicated as well as proprietary, so it is not possible to have that on Arduino (or outside the common environments). However that is not the only way to communicate with the Movesense sensor.

For low level BLE access, you can either define your own GATT service using CustomGATTService, or use one of the existing "out of the box" profiles (HRS or Nordic UART Service. These will be nicer in 2.0).

The new 2.0 comes with a sample that provides any sensor data over GATT (as a binary stream) and we've back ported it to 1.9.4 as well (find it in https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/downloads/).

In my opinion if you just want IMU-data, the "gatt_sensordata_app"-sample is by far the easiest way to go.

*Full disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*

Comment: Thank You for the reply. Where to get low level API to get GATT IMU binary stream data from the Movesense with gatt_sensordata_app microprogram? I will use Arduino and BLE Shield to connect Movesense.
And do we have Android example code to get GATT IMU binary stream data from the Movesense with gatt_sensordata_app microprogram?

Comment: The sample includes a WebBLE client code (use Chrome to view the index.html) that shows how to communicate with the app. For short: The binary format is the same generated format that is used by the DataLogger to store the data to the data memory. For details look in the "generated/sbem_code" in your build folder.

Comment: Thank you for this - this was exactly the information I was looking for. Is there any possibility the documentation might be updated to fully document the GATT interface please?